# Magento1.9 jquery calendar not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, calendar

I have added jquery calendar for a product to take date and time and kept as not required. If I add that product to cart without disturbing the date field its working.If I select date, time and trying add the product to cart means its showing field not complete. Can anyone help in this issue?

Comment: Please share the code which you did to add calendar

Comment: It's defaut code only. I didn't add anything. Where that calendar code will be?@Jaimin Sutariya

Comment: you can check by enabling template path